# Cannot get protocol with typealias to work in Swift

Tags: swift

Just trying to build a proof-of-concept lib in Swift with the following code:

```
import Foundation

protocol Resolver {
    typealias ResolvedType
    func get() -> ResolvedType
}

class FunctionResolver<T>: Resolver {
    typealias ResolvedType = T

    private var _resolver: () -> ResolvedType

    init(resolver: () -> ResolvedType) {
        _resolver = resolver
    }

    func get() -> ResolvedType {
        return _resolver()
    }
}


func singleton<T, U: Resolver where U.ResolvedType == T>(instance: T) -> U {
    return FunctionResolver({ () -> T in instance }) as U
}

class TestObject {
    init() { }
}

let obj = TestObject()
let r = singleton(obj)
```

However the last line fails with:

```
playground466.swift:30:9: error: cannot convert the expression's type 'TestObject' to type 'Resolver'
let r = singleton(obj)
        ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why is Swift trying to convert `obj` to a `Resolver`? I am not quite sure what I am missing there. I think this should work since all the type information is available inside the `singleton` method.

Am I introducing some kind of loops in the inferrencing system? How can I fix this so the last line works as intended (a resolver that resolves to same instance of `obj`)?

I am on the latest Xcode available on the dev portal.

---

**EDIT:** I tried simplifying it, still does not work:

```
func singleton<T: Resolver>(instance: T.ResolvedType) -> T {
    return FunctionResolver(resolver: { () -> T.ResolvedType in instance }) as T
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in this function:

```
func singleton<T, U>(instance: T) -> U {
    return FunctionResolver({ () -> T in instance }) as U
}
```

`U` cannot be inferred as an input parameter - instead it's the type of the variable you assign its return value used to infer the type. If you write:

```
let r = singleton(obj)
```

you are not providing enough info to determine what `U` is. So you should explicitly specify its type:

```
let r: FunctionResolver<TestObject> = singleton(obj)
```

I know... the error message doesn't help much :) As a general rule, if it doesn't make sense, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Wow, so protocol with typealias are even more limited than I've thought. This isn't the first time I have ran into issues with inferring return types. Needs to remember about that point next time. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're pushing the type inference system past it's limits.

`singleton()` function is parametrised with generic type and returns a value of that generic type. There is never any information about what type T actually is.

The easiest fix, since Swift doesn't support explicitly providing values for generics in function, is to determine the return type.

```
let obj = TestObject()
let r : FunctionResolver = singleton(obj)
```

Works properly.

But what if you doesn't want to specify the exact type, just that `r is Resolver`?

Tough luck. Swift doesn't support that. Protocols with associated types can be used only as a generic constrains, as the compiler error states.